# Jquery Change Input background color if entry matches PHP Array?

Tags: php, jquery, css, input

I have a simple form that has 3 fields. user, id, email.
I have 2 PHP arrays $user & $id

When a user enters there name into the user or id fields I want the respective php arrays checking and if the name or id is in the array then change the background color of the input box they are currently in.

If they update there entry then the checking should continue and if no match is found then revert the background back to it's original white color.

If they empty the input field then the color should change back to white.

The page may be preloaded with values, so I may be changing the background color using php on the initial load..

I've found this, which sort of works for the specified characters in it's array:

```
$('input').bind("change keyup", function() {
 var val = $(this).val();
 var regex = /["<>&]/g;
 if (val.match(regex)) {
   $(this).css("background", "red");
   val = val.replace(regex, "");
   $(this).val(val);
 }
 $("p").html(val);
});
```

I've tried to update it to support a php array, but it doesn't work and I don't know how to make it check either array and revert the color back.

This is what I have so far :

**[JFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LqPBL/)**

Thanks :)

**UPDATE**

I've got this working using the following :

```
$(function(){
 $('input').bind("change keyup", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).attr('id')=="user") {
    var check = <?php echo json_encode($user)?>;
 } else {
    var check = <?php echo json_encode($id)?>;
}
if ($.inArray(val, check) != -1) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
 } else {
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    }
  });
});
```

But is there a neater way to write this ?

Thanks :)

Comment: You should try this plugin instead: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: @Hardy - Thanks anyway to do this without additional plugins ?

Comment: So are you just trying to check for duplicate values? And set background to red if given value already exists in some fields?

Comment: Correct. If the user enters a value that is already in the array, set the background color of the input field they are currently to red. and revert it back to white if the either clear the input field or enter a value that is not in the array. Thx

Comment: I've got this working and have update the original post. Anyway to make the code neater ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use your php array in javascript, you can do this:

```
var myArray = <?php echo json_encode($myArray) ?>;
```

and do the javascript magic

Comment: Thanks I have this in my script, but it doesn't seem to work.
`var user = <?php echo json_encode($user)?>;`